# Removing "Test Pass Rate" from the "Analytics" Section in Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

Is it possible to remove the "Test Pass rate" Tile seen under the Analytics section of a CI pipeline in Azure DevOps?

I disabled Test Plan in the project settings and this tile is still showing.

[image]

I want the Analytics Section to display only the "Pipeline pass rate" and "Pipeline duration".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe not, this is a build-in feature for a build or release summary to view the top failing tests report. This report provides a granular view of the top failing tests in the pipeline, along with the failure details.

Disable Test Plan in Project Settings will not affect "Test pass rate" view on the pipeline summary page.

If you would like a related setting to control this function's visibility in Azure DevOps UI, create a suggestion ticket via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest